# Where is the index.php file in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to using the Symfony2 framework. I've worked a little with the Laravel framework previously and it has an `index.php` file in the `public` folder, which is the main entry point to the app. But I'm not sure where a similar `index.php` file in a Symfony framework project is to be found - does Symfony have something similar?

Comment: Symfony has no `index.php` file but a `app.php` and `app_dev.php` which replace the `index.php`.

Comment: See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html#executing-an-application-in-different-environments

Comment: @JayBlanchard means when I get the answer I should be given the reply about his answer

Comment: @tkausl Thanks I got this file

Comment: What do you mean? You have gotten answers on a couple of your questions and you have yet to accept any of them.

Comment: Accepting means checking the checkmark next to the answer. For example, @Alok's answer below is correct, but there is no checkmark next to it. You Have other questions where you have not done this as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no `index.php` file in Symfony framework distribution. But it has two files by default which works as a main file of the Framework.

They are **app.php** and **app_dev.php**, where `app.php` is a production environment's main page and `app_dev.php` is main page for development environment.
 Though they are called [front controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/front_controllers_and_kernel.html#the-front-controller).

> **app.php** and **app_dev.php** files are in the web/ directory. These are the very first PHP scripts executed when a request is processed.

Reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/front_controllers_and_kernel.html

**Note: This is true for Symfony 2/3 folder structure.**

Symfony 4 Updates:

In Symfony 4 `index.php` file is in `public/` folder. Unlike Symfony 2/3 the environment is decided from `.env` file of the root folder. In `.env` file we've `APP_ENV` parameter which decides the env of application.

Comment: This is now out-of-date and incorrect with the Symfony 4.x/5.x "Flex" structure.